# Lock exception while updating a table asynchronously in oracle adf

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-adf

my jdev version :11.1.1.7

In our adf application we have a requirement to upload heavy csv files(10k-100k rows) and process/validate each rows and update in the table with process/validation statuses.
The update is happening for each row by applying the view criteria with a primary key as bind variable and commiting each updated row
All of the above process is happening concurrently using java.util.concurrent utilities.

Everything is working fine but few rows encounter oracle.jbo.JboException: JBO-25014: Another user has changed the row with primary key oracle.jbo.Key[254 ].

I have tried updating the table at the end of the whole executor process and committing all updated rows in batch which works fine but this contradicts one of the requirements as user has to wait till end of the process to see the number of updated records in UI.

My queries :
1.How can i implement a thread safe DB commit operation in ADF in such scenario?
2.Each processed/validated row should be commited to DB so that the updated records can be viewed on UI by user

Answer (score 0):

after your every commit operation  use "executequery()" or "closerowset()" for your getviewobject.

eg:`public void closemaster() {
        this.getMasterView().closeRowSet();
    }`

or you can use:

```
    public void closemaster() {
    this.getMasterView().executeQuery();
}
```

both answers will work.

i think your problem will be solved.

update what happens.

Comment: i have used this in impl class you can bind methods and can access through operation binding in backing bean.